# Using “and” operator to compare two values

Tags: python, syntax, operators

Very new to python and trying to figure out how to use the and operator to check if a number is between 50 and 100. Tried using *and*, *&&* and *||* , but just getting invalid syntax python parser-16 error. If I take the *and* or alternative out of the code, then it partly works and dosn't give me a error message, though it dosn't check if the value is below 100, so presumly it must the *and* part that I'm doing wrong?

```
x = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100"))

if x < 50:
    print("That is below 50!")
elif x > 50 and < 100:
    print("That is above 50!")
else:
    print("That number is too high!")
```

Comment: On a side note, what do you do when `x == 50`? On another note, `elif x < 100:` only is sufficient (ignoring the `x == 50` case).

Answer (score 0):

close!

```
x = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100"))

if x < 50:
    print("That is below 50!")
elif x > 50 and x < 100:
    print("That is above 50!")
else:
    print("That number is too high!")
```

`if x > 50 and x < 100` you have to reference it each time you check if its true

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100: "))# for a better look

if x < 50:
    print("That is below 50!")
elif 100 >= x >= 50:# the numbers 50 and 100 shall be inclusive in one of the three params
    print("That is between 50 and 100!")
else:
    print("That number is too high!")
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify it more, you can write as below.

```
x = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100"))

if x < 50:
    print("That is below 50!")
elif 50 < x < 100:
    print("That is above 50!")
else:
    print("That number is too high!")
```

Comment: And as a matter of fact, I believe this is faster than doing `x > 50 and < 100`

Answer (score 0):

If x<50:

```
  print('Below 50')
```

elif x>50 and x<100:

```
  print('Between 50 and 100');
```

else:

```
  print('Above 100');
```

Try this